# UserControl Leaks when Called from Windows Service to Render Image

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, windows-services

I have a C# Windows Service which loads a custom WPF UserControl to render images that are later emailed to users.  This works fine, however, when viewing the memory usage from .Net Memory Profiler I see each instantiated instance of the control is leaked.  When reviewing the leaks it appears to be a delegate to the focus handler.  The custom user control does not subscribe to any event handlers.  I need a way to unload the control programmatically.  Here is the code:

```
        public string GetPercentGauge(long percent, long? max = 100)
        {
            var t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                GetPercentGaugeThread(fileName, percent, max);
            });
            t.Name = "UIThread";
            t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); 
            t.IsBackground = true; 
            t.Start();

            while (t.IsAlive)
                Thread.Sleep(30);

            return fileName;
        }
     
        private void GetPercentGaugeThread(string fileName, long percent, long? max = 100)
        {
            try
            {                
                var ctrl = new RowThresholdChartControl()
                {
                    DataContext = new BaseColumnChartItemViewModel(percent, max.Value)
                };                
                ctrl.DrawToPng(fileName, 200, 20);
                ctrl.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: "The custom user control does not subscribe to any event handlers" It must do or it would not leak. Check the owner of the delegate

Comment: Also, setting to null is pointless, and use `using` statements. That empty catch block smells too much

Comment: A WPF control expects to be running on a desktop with a UI. A Windows Service runs with no UI and no desktop. My guess is that your plan has a good chance to be doomed to failure.

Comment: I have narrowed it down to a call to Arrange(new Rect(new Size(width, height))); which allows the control to render the image.  This is functionality Windows Forms has always had.  Rendering graphics from services is normal behavior.  This is how all the server monitoring software packages operate. I find it hard to believe MS would have taken a huge step back with WPF over .Net Forms.  I tried looking for the parent to see if that helped...no parent. All I have to do is remark my call to Arrange and the control is finalized...but no image then.

Comment: After reading your answer, I wonder if the problem could be that you're not calling `Close()` before disposing the control. I think there's something going on, we may be able to help you further if you could include a [mre] through a console app and simple/empty control/window

Answer (score 0):

I have found a fix on my own, although it seems like a hack to me.  As stated above the memory profiler was pointing to a keyboard handler which made sense but the WPF API doesn't include methods to clear the offending delegates. I was going to start heading down the path of adding it to a Window using the native C API then send it a WM_CLOSE in hopes it should shut it down but that sounded like a nasty rat hole.  I don't know if that can even be done.  My next thought was to fire off an EXE to process the file.  I didn't like that idea either because this function can be called 1000s of times in a matter of seconds.

The fix:
Once I am done with rendering the control, I simply set the size of the control to 0. I figured the underlying code would be smart enough to remove the control since it no longer wants to either render it or process TAB key press events.  I also expected the removal to clean up the offending delegates and so it was.  Here is the rendering call which now allows for the 'ctrl' variable in the above code to be finalized.

```
        public void DrawToPng(string fileName, int width, int height)
        {
            Initialize();

            Measure(new Size(width, height));
            Arrange(new Rect(new Size(width, height)));            

            var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)ActualWidth, (int)ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            bitmap.Render(this);

            var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));

            using (var file = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
            {
                encoder.Save(file);
            }
            
            Measure(new Size(0, 0));
            InvalidateArrange();
            UpdateLayout();
        }
```